# Inserting data into regression network in keras

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, regression, keras

I am currently struggling to understand how i should train my regression network using keras.  I am not sure how I should pass my input data to the network.

Both the input data and the output data is stored as a list of numpy arrays.

Each input numpy array is a matrix which has (400 rows, x columns)
Each output numpy array is a matrix which has (x number of rows, 13 columns)

So input dimension is 400 and output is 13. 
But how do I pass each of these sets within the list to the training?

```
# Multilayer Perceptron
model = Sequential()    # Feedforward
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=400))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile('sgd', 'mse')
```

Just by parsing data into gives me this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_datapreprocess_mfcc_extraction_rnn.py", line 167, in <module>
    model.fit(train_set_data,train_set_output,verbose=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 620, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1034, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 961, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 51, in standardize_input_data
    '...')
Exception: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 270 arrays: [array([[ -1.52587891e-04,   3.05175781e-05,  -1.52587891e-04,
         -5.18798828e-04,   3.05175781e-05,  -3.96728516e-04,
          1.52587891e-04,   3.35693359e-04,  -9.15527344e-05,
          3.3...
```

Comment: Not as such..  Usually is the input stored as numpy.array but since each numpy.array is stored in a list, i am not sure how model.fit handles this. 
How can it correctly extract the data i want it to extract?

Comment: AFAIK, that should work if you feed input/output with the proper dimensions.

Comment: But... how should i feed it? The neural network is set to have the proper dimension. but how does model.fit extract the correct portion as input and output.

Comment: I think if you say `model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=32)`, then `X_train` and `Y_train` should have the proper dimensions.

Comment: Are you sure.. It seems bit like magic that the function is capable of taking the right parts of the matrix, without  explicitly specifying that each column in matrix A has to be mapped to each row in matrix B, and shall be done for each matrix in the list.

Comment: That's what the tutorial says. It looks like Keras has a google group or Slack group. You could try there too. If you try to run the code, nothing is going to blow up, and then you can work backwards from the error message.

Comment: It runs.. But I have no idea whether it is doing it right or wrong. No debug message it being printed.